# Trying to do login via JSON, but have runtime errors

Tags: android, json

This is my logcat

```
12-08 13:37:39.849: W/dalvikvm(5757): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at com.pmss.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:55)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
12-08 13:37:39.859: E/AndroidRuntime(5757):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my `Login.java`

```
public class Login extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener  {

private Button login,register;
private EditText email,password;
// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.14:1234/PMSS/login.php";      
  //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtext);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordtext);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        }
    });

    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        // For the main activity, make sure the app icon in the action bar
        // does not behave as a button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    /*case R.id.login:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        break;
    case R.id.register:
            Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        break;
*/
    default:
        break;
    }
}

//AsyncTask is a seperate thread than the thread that runs the GUI
    //Any type of networking should be done with asynctask.
    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //three methods get called, first preExecture, then do in background, and once do
        //in back ground is completed, the onPost execture method will be called.
            boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            int success;
            String Username = email.getText().toString();
            String Password = password.getText().toString();
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                       LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                System.out.print("Here");
                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

As I should mention, Once I click the login button it appears Attemping Login... then a few second more become force close.. I identified the logcat errors but dont know what to correct it..

By the way, my android apps was connect to Wi-fi which my laptop also connect to the same Wi-Fi and I'm able to access login.php from my mobile phone with that URL which is `http://192.168.XX.XX:1234/PMSS/login.php`

this is my activity.login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:useDefaultMargins="true"
tools:ignore="ExtraText" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/userid"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/userid"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/password"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/userid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pos_malaysia"        
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_main"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/newuser"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/button_login" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/newuser"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/register"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
    android:text="@string/newuser" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/button_register" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/login"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" >

</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the line number **122** in `Login.java`

Comment: `String Username = email.getText().toString();` this is line 122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Your Async   `class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {`

You cannot pass `Intent` in `doInBackground` so that error came try like below code

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;
        String res;
        String Username = email.getText().toString();
        String Password = password.getText().toString();
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
            System.out.print("Here");
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            return null;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", res);
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return ;
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String Username = email.getText().toString();
            String Password = password.getText().toString();
            new AttemptLogin(Username,Password).execute();
        }
    });
```

and Async

```
 class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    //three methods get called, first preExecture, then do in background, and once do
    //in back ground is completed, the onPost execture method will be called.
        boolean failure = false;
   String res;
   String Username; 
   String Password;
   int success;
   public AttemptLogin(String Username, String Password) {
            this.Username = Username;
            this.Password = Password;
   }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", Password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                   LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
            System.out.print("Here");
            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            res = json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            return res;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", res);
                Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, res, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: the `onPostExecute(int success)` I have errors on json object which is `json cannot be resolved` @Tamilan

Comment: @Nick try like my edit.

Comment: more erros coming out how to like? T_T

Comment: `class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, int>`
The error said `Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token`

Comment: @Nick sorry edited in intent mistakenly added return now i removed check out.

Comment: some errors still exist `class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, int>` The error said `Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token` 
and `return success` in `protected String doInBackground(String... args)` indicate the errors is `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String`

Comment: @Nick check it i changed it `protected void onPostExecute(int success) {`

Comment: even u change that to int success the errors I mention still exist....~ T_T

Comment: @Nick check my edit change all to strings and try it. i edited all async in the edit.

Comment: Now I have no compilation errors but runtime error again which when I click the login button and it forced close the apps again

Comment: @Nick post that error.

Comment: edited my logcat on my question

Comment: @Nick what is the line number **55** in `Login.java`

Comment: line 55 is `String Username = email.getText().toString();`

Comment: @Nick post you `activity_login.xml`

Comment: posted my `activity_login.xml`

Comment: @Nick there is no `emailtext` and `passwordtext` `EditText` so that NPE

Comment: yea i found that eventually I check the `activity.login.xml` sorry for my silly mistake ~~ although now I attemping login in the system and its loading for 2 mins++ since I'm using XAMPP server and MySQL for my local database